# Focus Lab Bootstrap config for sub directory?

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

Ok, I have been using the Focus Lab Bootstrap for a while and its awesome. But I have come across a new problem when trying to use a testing URL that isn't a standard domain/sub.domain.

How would I set up an environment like http://xx.xx.xx.x/test/ ?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if i've left out a pertinent piece of info!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't have 2 environments on the same domain, I believe you can override the main `$base_url` and `$base_path` variables separately in each environment config file. So, for example, in `config/config.dev.php`, you'd put this after the `$env_db` variables:

```
$base_url   = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/test';
$base_path  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/';
```

So it loads `config/config.master.php` with the default variables, then it loads `config.dev.php` and updates the base path variables to point to your subdirectory.

I haven't tested this though, just an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put this **after** the line in config.master.php that sets $base_path and $base_url so it would overwrite those variables if they were passed in from config.local.php.